# How to Generate Replication Reports from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, snapshot

I have number of databases being replicated over night. I need to know if there is a way to generate report or Query their Start Time and End Time for each one. Secondly, is there a way to get / Query the Replication Plan?

Thanks,

Comment: I'd recommend moving this question to the database stackexchange site; it's kind of off-topic here.

Comment: R u using sql server replication architecture?

Comment: Using Sql server agent